# Variable out of scope not working

Tags: javascript, scope

How can I call the `senator_party` info outside of the bio info loop but also within the `if(current_legislator.type === "senator")` statement?

My goal with this code is to:

- Loop through data to get senator data - works
- check for senator and use just senator data - works
- Loop through senator bio data to get party info - works
- Display party info outside of bio info loop - doesn't work

I read a bunch of articles on this and the consensus seemed to be if you create the variable outside of a functions scope, then if you update the variable inside a new function it will updated the variable information outside of the scope.

I you you can get a better feel for what I am trying to do in the comments in the code.

```
 $(congressional_district.current_legislators).each(function(index, current_legislator) {

      // check if Senator
      if(current_legislator.type === "senator") {
        // store empty party to use outside of scope
        var senator_party;

        // loop from bio info
        $(current_legislator.bio).each(function(index, bio_item) {

          // store new info in party variable
          var senator_party = bio_item.party;

          // call variable in alert - this works 
          alert(senator_party);

        });

        // call new variable outside of scope - returns undefined
        alert(senator_party);

      }
    })
```

Comment: That's a different variable.

Comment: You're re-declaring the variable inside the `.each()` callback.

Comment: Ahh so remove the "var =" inside the each loop!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var senator_party = bio_item.party;
```

inside the loop. To:

```
senator_party = bio_item.party;
```

So that you are not re-creating the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring the variable again in the each function, had to remove the "var ="
$(congressional_district.current_legislators).each(function(index, current_legislator) {

```
  // check if Senator
  if(current_legislator.type === "senator") {
    // store empty party to use outside of scope
    var senator_party;

    // loop from bio info
    $(current_legislator.bio).each(function(index, bio_item) {

      // store new info in party variable
      senator_party = bio_item.party;

      // call variable in alert - this works 
      alert(senator_party);

    });

    // call new variable outside of scope - returns undefined
    alert(senator_party);

  }
})
```